# Add new row to gridview

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, data-binding, gridview

I'm using a gridview to display and access a sql database and using databinding. I'm also using autogenerate columns as one gridview has multiple sources and toggles between them. What would be the best way to allow the user to insert a new row?

Would a listview be better?

Comment: When do you want to insert the row? PageLoad?

Comment: Not sure I understand. The user is looking at a gridview of data and I want to give them the ability to add a new row. Modified original question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to to add a detailsview, set it to the datasource of the gridview and done.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the `DataGridView.EditMode` property to something other than EditProgramatically?

Answer (score 0):

- FormView on the page, DefaultMode = Insert, and provide an Insert Template.
- Add buttons / visibility toggles / datahookup etc. as needed.

Comment: Formview? Where is the DefaultMode option?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.defaultmode.aspx